# How to save/edit object and refresh datagrid using request factory

Tags: gwt, requestfactory

I started with dynatableref example of Request Factory. I read request factory document. but still I am unclear about life cycle or flow of client to server. 
I want to make a call to server. Insert data and update grid also. It is easy with RPC call. But I don't understand how to do with Request Factory.
This is one method of request factory. It call persist method automatically of server. It refresh grid also automatically. can I anybody tell how is it working?

```
   context.fire(new Receiver<Void>() {
      @Override
      public void onConstraintViolation(Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> errors) {
        // Otherwise, show ConstraintViolations in the UI
        dialog.setText("Errors detected on the server");
        editorDriver.setConstraintViolations(errors);
      }

      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Void response) {
        // If everything went as planned, just dismiss the dialog box
        dialog.hide();
      }
    });
```

I want to edit some data in to grid also. is this method help me? or I have to write other method.
I wrote other method like

```
  requestFactory.schoolCalendarRequest().savePerson(personProxy).fire(new Receiver<PersonProxy>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(PersonProxy person) {
          // Re-check offset in case of changes while waiting for data
             dialog.hide();
        }
      });
```

This is not refreshing grid. why?

Answer (score 1):

The flow client-server of the `RuequestFactory` is similar to `RPC` or any `XMLHTTP` request

1) You invoke a remote method on the server.

2) You receive a response in the `Receiver` object (which is the `Callback` object). In `onSeccess` Method you get the returned object if everything went well. `onFailure` you get an error if something went wrong.

So to populate the Person table from data retrieved from the server the code should look something like this

```
 requestFactory.schoolCalendarRequest().getPersonList(param1).fire(new Receiver<List<PersonProxy>>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(List<PersonProxy> personList) {
       personTable.getDataProvider().setList(personList);
    }
  });
```

Now when you edit a Person (e.g. name ) it's important to initialize and use the same `RequestContext` until you call `fire` on the request. So the part where you update the Person's name should look something like this

```
column.setFieldUpdater(new FieldUpdater<Person, String>() {
  @Override
  public void update(PersonProxy personProxy, String value) {
    RequestContext requestContext =  requestFactory.schoolCalendarRequest()
    PersonProxy personProxy= requestContext.edit(personProxy);
    personProxy.setName(value);
        requestFactory.schoolCalendarRequest().savePerson(personProxy).fire(new Receiver<PersonProxy>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(PersonProxy person) {
            //Do something after the update
         }
        });
      }
  });
```

The interaction with the `RequestFactory` should be placed in a `Presenter`, so you should probably consider implementing a `MVP` pattern.